# How to limit result data from Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and I am wondering if I should use Eloquent Query Builder or just raw SQL.
When I am pulling data from MySql with Eloquent I get a lot of unnessesary stuff.

My approach with Eloquent Query Builder:

```
$query = Document::where('owner', $user_id);
$docs = $query->take(2)->get();
return $docs;
```

and the result I get:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[191]
protected 'items' => 
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Document)[189]
      protected 'table' => string 'documents' (length=9)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=12)
          'id' => int 2
          'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'description' => null
          'status' => int 0
          'files' => null
          'uid' => string 'gregdf' (length=6)
          'path' => string '[]' (length=2)
          'owner' => int 1
          'workspace' => int 1
          'flow' => int 1
          'created_at' => string '2014-12-10 10:10:10' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=12)
          'id' => int 2
          'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'description' => null
          'status' => int 0
          'files' => null
          'uid' => string 'gregdf' (length=6)
          'path' => string '[]' (length=2)
          'owner' => int 1
          'workspace' => int 1
          'flow' => int 1
          'created_at' => string '2014-12-10 10:10:10' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*' (length=1)
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
  1 => 
    object(Document)[187]
      protected 'table' => string 'documents' (length=9)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=12)
          'id' => int 3
          'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'description' => null
          'status' => int 0
          'files' => null
          'uid' => string 'gregdf' (length=6)
          'path' => null
          'owner' => int 1
          'workspace' => int 1
          'flow' => int 1
          'created_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=12)
          'id' => int 3
          'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'description' => null
          'status' => int 0
          'files' => null
          'uid' => string 'gregdf' (length=6)
          'path' => null
          'owner' => int 1
          'workspace' => int 1
          'flow' => int 1
          'created_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*' (length=1)
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean true
```

My approach with SQL:

```
$sqlArgs = array(
        'workspace' => $args['workspace'],
        'usr' => $user_id
    );

 $query = 'select d.title, d.description, d.created_at
                      from documents as d
                      inner join userDocuments as ud on ud.document = d.id
                      where ud.user = :usr and d.workspace = :workspace  limit 0, 2 ';
 $docs = DB::select($query, $sqlArgs);

 return $docs;
```

and the result (this is what I really need):

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
  object(stdClass)[185]
    public 'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
    public 'description' => null
    public 'created_at' => string '2014-12-10 10:10:10' (length=19)
1 => 
  object(stdClass)[189]
    public 'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
    public 'description' => null
    public 'created_at' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

So which approach is better? Or maybe I can limit the amount of data in Eloquent approach somehow?

UPDATE: Both above examples are querying for different sets of records, but what is important is how many data is returnet for each record.

Comment: Please add the code to your question and don't just link to it. Also at the moment the code (and result) is quite a lot. Try to reduce it to the minimum or clearly explain where we have to look

Comment: Please insert your code into the question. Do not provide links, because they will become stale.

Comment: Why does the amount of data matter? Are you worried about performance?

Comment: Yes. I am wondering about performance when I will query for much more records.

Comment: Funny. I was just trying to check if JSON of this collection will also have so much data. It turns out - NO, it is clean and simple. I also noticed that there is toArray() method, which didn't work for me before, but now it works and the result is what I was expecting :) So I changed $query->take(2)->get(); to $query->take(2)->get()->toArray(); and I think this solves my problem.

Comment: But the question remains - whis approach is better with performance in mind?

Comment: The raw SQL will perform better. However you probably won't notice a difference. Anyways, if you decide not to use Eloquent models you should consider using the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries) in the background it will build and run the same query but you get a nicer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what fields you are not interested in.

```
class Car extends Eloquent {

    protected $hidden = array('created_at');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Select](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) for what you wanted column like the following

```
$query = Document::where('owner', '=', $user_id)->lists('title', 'description', 'created_at');
```

It's will got only `title`, `description` and `created_at` columns.
For limiting eloquent query, you can use `take` with `select` like the following

```
$query = Document::where('owner', '=', $user_id)->lists('title', 'description', 'created_at')->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: Yup, tried that before, but how can I specify 2-4 columns?

Comment: I had some problems with this. When I queried one filed in list - all went ok. But with few fields - I got only one result record.

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a by design matter. Eloquent is an ORM (Read thoroughly about ORMs), that is it represents all records through objects and all records and their related records can be manipulated in a more object oriented way. You get to query the database and/or make its schema in PHP and not touch SQL at all. This way a plethora of abstractions can be placed on the DB.

To provide food for thought, one can through eloquent, manipulate the same DB differently in multiple deployments, set distinctly different profiles for a single table which may have their own primary keys and/or relationships.

Hand tailored SQL will always be faster than using any ORM. It really depends on what you judge as the better option.

Though the `toArray()` method is cleaner, I tend to avoid it. You can extract the field values of a single model by `$fieldValues = $model->attributes`.